# JAVA SWT Animated GIF

Tags: java, swt, animated-gif

I need to add animated gif in form of spinner, into some SWT widget like for example Label. This Label will be as default `labelSpiner.setEnabled(false)`. When I start some long duration operation this Label with spinner will show (`labelSpinner.setEnabled(true)`)in right corner of window.

Normaly Image can be added to Label by `labelSpinner.setImage(arg0)`

If I add this SPINNER.GIF normal way into Label, it wont animate, its only static Image.

Does anybody know how to add animated gif (for example some spinner) into SWT based JAVA SE app widget? I browsed many examples but many of them were useless, and those good were too complicated.

I would like to do it very simple.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Posting the approaches you already tried would make sure, that they aren't posted as answers.

Comment: I voted to close this question since it's very difficult to know what you are asking, what you have already tried and which problems you are facing. Please improve the question so that users are able to help you

Comment: +1 See the [Link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html).

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the Eclipse article about [SWT `Images`](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Animation)?

This part will load the image and display it in a `Canvas`:

```
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Idea_SWT_Animation.gif"));
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell,SWT.NONE);
image = new Image(display,loader.data[0]);
int imageNumber;
final GC gc = new GC(image);
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent event){
        event.gc.drawImage(image,0,0);
    }
});
```

And this part updates the gif:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int delayTime = loader.data[imageNumber].delayTime;
        while(currentTime + delayTime * 10 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
            // Wait till the delay time has passed
        }
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                // Increase the variable holding the frame number
                imageNumber = imageNumber == loader.data.length-1 ? 0 : imageNumber+1;
                // Draw the new data onto the image
                ImageData nextFrameData = loader.data[imageNumber];
                Image frameImage = new Image(display,nextFrameData);
                gc.drawImage(frameImage,nextFrameData.x,nextFrameData.y);
                frameImage.dispose();
                canvas.redraw();
            }
        });
    }
};
shell.open();
thread.start();
```

Comment: yeap, but I had some problems with that

Comment: @ToKra Well, you will have to explain what didn't work. Otherwise no one is able to help you...

Comment: +1 @Baz Can you please tell how to animate the image in table view.
Something like this
`Image image1 = new Image(display,myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("1.png"));
Image image2 = new Image(display,myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("2.png"));`
  
`item.setImage(image1);
item.setImage(image2);`

Comment: What's missing here, and from the SWT sample it was adopted from, is looping in the Thread to keep updating the GIF.  As it's currently written only the first frame will be rendered.

Answer (score 3):

After trying at least 3 different animated GIF examples, none of which worked, I started working on my own, based mainly on the answer above.

Here is a complete running example including:

- a base64 decoder (courtesy of http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/ )
- spinner GIF
- main method

Remove the main method, base64 methods, and image data, and you will have a working animated GIF canvas.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class AnimatedGif extends Canvas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] d = decode(b64.toCharArray(), 0, b64.length());
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

        AnimatedGif gif = new AnimatedGif(shell, SWT.NONE);
        gif.setLocation(10,10);
        gif.setSize(16, 16);
        gif.load(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(d));
        shell.open();
        gif.animate();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();

    }

    private final ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
    private int img = 0;
    private volatile boolean animating = false;
    private Thread animateThread;

    public AnimatedGif(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }

    public void load (InputStream resource) throws IOException {
        loader.load(resource);
    }

    public void animate() {
        if (animateThread == null) {
            animateThread = createThread();
            animateThread.setDaemon(true);
        }

        if (animateThread.isAlive())
            return;

        animateThread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        animating = false;
        if (animateThread != null)
            try {
                animateThread.join();
                animateThread = null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
    }

    private Thread createThread() {
        return new Thread() {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
            public void run() {
                animating = true;
                while(animating) {
                    img = (img == loader.data.length-1) ? 0 : img + 1;
                    int delayTime = Math.max(50, 10*loader.data[img].delayTime);
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long ms = Math.max(currentTime + delayTime - now, 5);
                    currentTime += delayTime;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(ms);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!display.isDisposed())
                        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ImageData nextFrameData = loader.data[img];
                                Image frameImage = new Image(display, nextFrameData);
                                new GC(AnimatedGif.this).drawImage(frameImage, nextFrameData.x, nextFrameData.y);
                                frameImage.dispose();
                                //canvas.redraw();
                            }
                        });
                }

                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new GC(AnimatedGif.this).fillRectangle(
                                0,
                                0,
                                getBounds().width,
                                getBounds().height);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    private static final char[] map1 = new char[64];
    static {
        int i = 0;
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            map1[i++] = c;
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            map1[i++] = c;
        for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
            map1[i++] = c;
        map1[i++] = '+';
        map1[i++] = '/';
    }

    private static final byte[] map2 = new byte[128];
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < map2.length; i++)
            map2[i] = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            map2[map1[i]] = (byte) i;
    }

    public static byte[] decode(char[] in, int iOff, int iLen) {
        if (iLen % 4 != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Length of Base64 encoded input string is not a multiple of 4.");
        while (iLen > 0 && in[iOff + iLen - 1] == '=')
            iLen--;
        int oLen = (iLen * 3) / 4;
        byte[] out = new byte[oLen];
        int ip = iOff;
        int iEnd = iOff + iLen;
        int op = 0;
        while (ip < iEnd) {
            int i0 = in[ip++];
            int i1 = in[ip++];
            int i2 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            int i3 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            if (i0 > 127 || i1 > 127 || i2 > 127 || i3 > 127)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int b0 = map2[i0];
            int b1 = map2[i1];
            int b2 = map2[i2];
            int b3 = map2[i3];
            if (b0 < 0 || b1 < 0 || b2 < 0 || b3 < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int o0 = (b0 << 2) | (b1 >>> 4);
            int o1 = ((b1 & 0xf) << 4) | (b2 >>> 2);
            int o2 = ((b2 & 3) << 6) | b3;
            out[op++] = (byte) o0;
            if (op < oLen)
                out[op++] = (byte) o1;
            if (op < oLen)
                out[op++] = (byte) o2;
        }
        return out;
    }

    static String b64 =
            "R0lGODlhEAAQAPf/AMra5KO9zOzz9s3b5MDS3aS+zZOwwsrZ4+bt89jm7IKftuLr" + 
            "8ZCswH6bs9vn7qrD0+Ts8oqnvYKetomlu8PV4t7p79Pg6dzp79vm7q/F1aC6zdTi" + 
            "6bbL2XqYsdDf55SwxK/H1ajC0Yajudzp7q7E087c59Xi6niWr8XY4qW/0LnM2aO9" + 
            "zoyov7bK2djk7ICbtIOhtt7p7pq1yc3b5sDU38DR39vm7LDH1afA0Yqovebu85Gt" + 
            "wouovsvZ5oCdtunv9IaiuXyZscrb5qnC0Zezxdjj64WiuZ65y7vQ3N/p8OLq8avE" + 
            "1MTX4o6rwJaxxLnN29jm7a7F1dvm7Y2qwH2bs7zQ3Jizx9Df6djj7HmXr+Tt8rvO" + 
            "26/E1LrO3KC5zKW+z8/e577Q3oCctYShubTK2HyasZGtwHuYsdTg6enw89/p76zE" + 
            "04iku+Lr8LXJ2JKvw+Xt8tHf583b57vP3pu2ycjY45m0yNvp7qzE1bHI13qZsaK8" + 
            "zn2aspq0yODp8Nfi6svb5oaiuuDp76vE09Hf6ZWzxMfY4qnC087e5+rx9eLs8pSv" + 
            "xL/R3rPI2Nfj64ajuq7E1Y2pv7rQ2+Lp8J65yarC1JKvxLzR3nybsrzQ3unw9HmY" + 
            "sLvR3LPI17nO28rY5Iqlvc3c5urx9Iakus/f53iVrtPi6cnY436btNTi6tfi67PK" + 
            "1rHI2H6bspy3yJ63ydXi7JezxKjA0ZGuwNjk64CbtazE0Zezx8DR3NXi68TX4Nvn" + 
            "7e7097vP24CctH2atIqlvN7o7tPh6Nzn7JGvwK/F1MbX4dHg6MfY4b7S3c/e5n2b" + 
            "srjN2ezy9eDq78rb4svb473R2+Ts8cHV3r7R3eXu8rfN2JSvwo+tv9/p7pSxw6C7" + 
            "ytbj6cTX36zD1NHg5vL3+KnB0Onx9cPV35y4yLPJ1dnl7LnO2cHU3avD0bnP2sDV" + 
            "4pKvwdfk7O7z99Xi6XqXsNTi6N3o7sjY4ubv8s7c5qvE0env842svuLs8Z64yJm0" + 
            "xZq2x46svuLq8P///yH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQ" + 
            "AAAIvQD/CRR4poEEf0q0DFz478SZFwqAxPC3AAEChqU6GAQSwcHEihcFntAoQUQE" + 
            "BgkcVKCI4IdAkiYZfCiScmXFfzBzMFhYk6K/jScZ/uspSEFMJ0KxpIxxAQgPBk5k" + 
            "CDVRBIoDDE8/yNAg1MIGmglkyvDy5cHCEh4smIC14d/WLyGGQGpBA4UQtBYsCDyy" + 
            "AseDByBaqKhhqAfaKwNTPIiyBAQZFUjqGmY4KEMGEG5UdAlDgYlQgQ9IdOJQhRPD" + 
            "gAAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAI1gD/CRR4IkiZBjx0DFwoMIueBj58EBGlRAtD" + 
            "h1TEKAikgJUOfxAWbsKk0QgbFjmEJEkiEIFAVBLGjMoxZUcfG1AEhvz3YiOoSAz/" + 
            "3VHzD8EPIxNYMPgQVMqFSRAWsGjyhoidoAmkVFjgb8eHPq80BMWS4I4fQZboaFiB" + 
            "I6gJFxhGXDiyJ4WsIZUWItrwxwYGF/9ShHjwIEOLGkwAkbJgAgvgwHjwLLnB4QmF" + 
            "HnI8oNmwYSCJDCDycPBUA8UMMHGuMHxAQvSTTBTqzBASVCCIFlWQ1KDAMCAAIfkE" + 
            "BQAA/wAsAAAAABAAEAAACMsA/wkUeKZDmSANfAxc+K8BlRe+FNRSMIbKMoYwFCjI" + 
            "CAOGEY1iqgyMMIHkhJIRgE14JImXEoEMdpiJyYBBpBxN5mjyB+GfEytWiNyyspCR" + 
            "ohE8f2jQ4GUpw38JLvBE8CVFChxDnkadOmTQoRCQtEqFoKNYlAdrMohNyiVDlBst" + 
            "5ix0lAAphAX/uNwgoyIMDQpMdJWAgrSNQC6NODyZQ4NJnVAWCFeYNLDFli6MDM3w" + 
            "gCZXgl0XGFaRVAPFZjQmHEl5KhCaaQ+EKDAMCAAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAI" + 
            "2wD/CRRIJUiHLCdODFz47xEMCT5eNOBjMAjDKTkisBFh5J+CiK3KDFy06I2ZJix4" + 
            "TJggYowCPr8EHqEjg4iTDzuaTGExQYEVQP9WCN3j5cjCKXYuIfihZEiIEDhwMBSo" + 
            "KMYCLSSiHAqxZKoNB0kW/MvAZQmJDFP/jfi3AMEaEDcacZgqZSACEjfIcOjCZKEL" + 
            "DGr+IdDxz42KJ0hQCEFkQVUCB34WEP6nYssWGqfkxDH1B8MIfwv8DUQShsKnEoQ2" + 
            "FMEQI4lohhR6gLFg4q+DCmn/zQBzZUMqGwwDAgAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAI" + 
            "uAD/CRTIgAcQBQ06DFz474iMDwVFSEh4gmGKFRoeMogAZGKHUgMHPcDxxYsMJxsl" + 
            "UhSYIcqDEF8yosyh8sy/BxmWPBjyYGFKCS/OkABBFBLDfxsPNujkhkyLFkchcpTA" + 
            "QYVVGkeLJHAQw1+VLkhqoDi6tasSTmFoGBJSYuHWCv4WaPlHAUWPEh4smMDyNi4C" + 
            "gUzu5t2g1QHcBQj+CsSrtwgUw34VD7xiAVZZvz+OCtyQAMMFQf4YBgQAIfkEBQAA" + 
            "/wAsAAAAABAAEAAACNYA/wkUeMTSDhZGXgxc+C9Fij10PjSZoADVJoYk8IRIoaHP" + 
            "GxaBJGDKMvBBBjwPZK14RYQBqDFi9AwkAWLJgyE4NNj5EGmUAiokQeTJcyNDJYY5" + 
            "jMQ80YKD0xYM/01ho6BBkCpPPD2pEfVgIB9lkGSqQYFJ1D45FPhoQBZFD0BRbQhh" + 
            "RYQHhToz5JBCxBBKEh2idPybAcaDhQ0msCSQcudfEn9KBAqJg8bEHxeLL6gRCEHL" + 
            "wCsbsNjAcKfCpH8Qov7b4ALDCD8LICD4N1u1iwuC/C34wTAgACH5BAUAAP8ALAAA" + 
            "AAAQABAAAAjNAP8JFMil2JAvGpwMXPiPC5cMUQal0GCFQQSGLRrdiPLgUAovVnZM" + 
            "gDGwyhYOZG6sCYFDAxEzERQ0ECipyxMVLTJAGqLhFoMJCqj8o1CD0ZwwcxaGHPni" + 
            "DAoUhmjQYPjvpwJfHWZoZUKBKkwYCsp4GFunK8NIEWDUCkIIDZpQuqjmAGZEJgUT" + 
            "uSyUcLSQUROgY8b8c5QACpQEiBErmvMoqEApu0ZIvkD5wghNksQsG3ihgr/PoD/z" + 
            "qsJwUhsIqFNDUEJV4IIfOhAg+MEwIAAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAI1wD/CRRI" + 
            "Yk0GEkNWDFz4T4WbGyC4RAmx4sgihki2qCBzY8khinQWTRlIIcyWJxwakQiBY4+M" + 
            "NzkeCaRAgQaSLhwyLMHhhYiZCDD+zejx6RQKJguPOGnCRgIVMGBKyBHC8N8HFiJ8" + 
            "BLligVAcRFV38DDyosMGExtMWajaZMK/BllSuSjyR1XVKRMU8DlhA4PfBC4WTsGq" + 
            "9cQ/BzFGOMAg5Z+Nf3YmjCkrsEISf37U/FOs6JICBa2CDPS3YMHAJDEQWOFThqE/" + 
            "HQj+lV7wA9CvqgJhx9aihGFAACH5BAUAAP8ALAAAAAAQABAAAAjAAP8JFMipCodO" + 
            "JB4MXPiPCYUwXVS4AZEhwyCGJXqgoIFEBRkQS6I8SDHwioeMhmqoaAHiwQMcK44I" + 
            "tGDhpJCNLSANCfFFg4x/G2CZqFli4YMvXmR8YJAgQZENFhj+87mUBwYHUIqYkCrD" + 
            "CQMeQC7EcJAAi1SvEUQoEOSvAlmpDCIAkdDA34K2bwcyyPGPbod/CO66dbo0Ld2B" + 
            "PwLjTRBXhN8TAxEgEDhWrt9SDCXfjQFEwYszkKX+06LEH90zDAMCACH5BAkAAP8A" + 
            "LAAAAAAQABAAAAjWAP8JFEihBpIqLUAMXPhPyIw6FDI94ZCHxAOGV+KAmYGihieK" + 
            "IDKQGLhhAxoPcnpQmHhjCR48KQS6wGLCAilATGq0yPDgQYiYLjDY+LMB0cJKQ2Sl" + 
            "2HPkwggMLkww/IdjhQY6lgT5uZMAy1QNr/p82OFvQQUpCabaIfKmCYsFECZdkDL1" + 
            "AwMWE4z8QPBPzZ2pkUAFUvBCIASBUGz02TElx6gxElAJ5PsvSRIhOViwMaJADKZN" + 
            "CyH408FKwWAxVPRkYahFiSgiPnw0UD11oA4eDcoEOcEwIAAh+QQJAAD/ACwAAAAA" + 
            "EAAQAAAIyAD/CRw4zAYtYdwGKvyXz1m2YAaF1XsGbWE1aW3UQKQVb8CBA8YG3qMH" + 
            "Z4E8c++OKQMwD9k4XALTpClp7tsxD8oGIOs2DaamRDPbOFMIwBi6ZARwuQMKp83C" + 
            "fwSiVUEqgKnThdTU9YrWq5nVp73OMWNmzWvQp6tWlUv7j6m4AQpt2Utny1a4tmnc" + 
            "AQhAaVuAAAUABxaoCdwzfq70UaJEzpUrSo8HQjNQqNC+WLEKZda8cNYsIoWuFTLA" + 
            "bhaxpwK1EWOADV+/hQEBACH5BAUAAP8ALAAAAAAQABAAAAjcAP8JFGgj1YYrYGYM" + 
            "XPivggMMLkxYANODAsN//pLEwFBkA6ESnyiEQTLQ3wJ/IzD8MRVHzikaW7aoEKhj" + 
            "gR8HCVRZQCQEBZInKtz804HAnxqIC5l04UDmBgkEEPxdkHKRQ6MbINYgODkiwcUM" + 
            "JJZwybA1iQMbF5eEOBSFhJYFMRR5ZYgDR4gQQ5T8QHDJzpSFR7zsWUH4HyArCiaw" + 
            "mNJkxwcnRGTQOSLwFx8FY0RMmMCDRRMzbxYtGlim1QsfCmAYEcEmQo6/C4N0CMKn" + 
            "wWkJMB5dFHjiRJbZVBgGBAAh+QQFAAD/ACwAAAAAEAAQAAAIuQD/CRToT9AFDAk2" + 
            "DFz47weCBf5iOEgAy8IVhgge+qvgAEoRExY8lBiYESLHBEU2hCzRg4lAjSexgBTZ" + 
            "AwWFf1pMTlxYQoghGmE4KYm4kyGKGki6VCGKkuE/GiqicpAAJAKDD05btCDjplMD" + 
            "BVUZOIUEoiyJMy8kiLC68MGQB0syPPh3poHaHAycyNDwJcSDKBkEnuhgd21eGV6+" + 
            "4HgwaGApwlStfti7IgXDwYV5XJVxxKlAwmA1MwwIACH5BAUAAP8ALAAAAAAQABAA" + 
            "AAjVAP8JFPhjgT9BF1wMXPgPQUMIC/yMwOBiA0OBEP5NqnAHgw0sG64M1JLxn5oL" + 
            "UhK4+GMCTRwhApX4S/LvTkosJjZY8ABmxj8donQkgcIQESk5M+pQ4EGElRAbFwH1" + 
            "QEGhRgMfCnL0ucikaiYkZXwEYrHjYo0nnp5UCdJAAZspF1twmNvihB4xRnIwrJTh" + 
            "Rp48IP5loaJgVKQPdjTgGPJgCQgSA++OAcWAyKsVsh7gyfBgYBZMEsa+6aMhRQg8" + 
            "kBduQqVgQpMPdPakSHFR4AsjZC0dYRgQACH5BAUAAP8ALAAAAAAQABAAAAjRAP8J" + 
            "FFgBAQIdP2wMXPhPCYSHECG0GcaQBi9/GDNirNBuIA8xkjSNuEDywoiTuzYIpKLg" + 
            "0RxFCWLGhAIlgaN/D4womNCE0UJHJSzkMpHphQIjwFgw/KcrFBo0hCTUghHBy1JG" + 
            "dTx4CNVAAVUiS9cxmTGjRxlfO80spUHDEAoUE17AmLDDysIuYeYwqnHpH8sJDG5p" + 
            "CFGJSwsVT7pIEtg1ghkiGnCEWHODDIctWwbOreslxaEHUW40usEwAgMrGlIMipKB" + 
            "y5qlAp1o+DKExBeGAQEAIfkEBQAA/wAsAAAAABAAEAAACNcA/wkUqETLPwQIByr8" + 
            "xwPQjwUQD+rAsBATHysIYiQZCNHfwBWtFCi4pMjBiH9q/PhLkkBghxdjJtj5Z+Of" + 
            "FAwmYzj4xyaIDxEsmih0kQCDUSzw+CiYsGPhP1V/irhIlaXBvwmWnFowtcHElTIv" + 
            "jPD44FRIHEIWrvgESnahEDklwMygIoFNEydHFFJAcepTjzr/YEQwQ8QLjgfeOHRB" + 
            "QoMCBYFAcryRsQdHCBKNODzZEobDwCmL6KwIcWjJDTIqtiBZaObI6ChcQNxw48ap" + 
            "wBVDSGRYs2ZhQAA7";
}
```

Comment: This has a serious bug. You need to declare your GC just once.. You are declaring one for each iteration through the animation... So add: final GC gc = new GC(Display.getCurrent()); and use   gc.drawImage(frameImage, nextFrameData.x, nextFrameData.y); instead of new GC(AnimatedGif.this)

Comment: Create the GC in the constructor once, with gc = new GC(this);

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! Is it a bug or just an inefficiency? It worked last time I ran it years ago.

Comment: A bug and memory leak. Will crash with out of handles if you leave it running.

Answer (score 1):

here is sample code provided. Basically this is how it works. Unlike other image formats, Animated GIF will have setof ImageData ( like a frame in an animation). You will render this image data on Cavans with the delay that you want.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DisplayananimatedGIF.htm

Comment: I have seen similiar one with more threads, it is working, but what I want is to use GIF like simple progress dialog or progrss status showing during downloading some data from net. I want to make it simple, similiar like in Android progress dialog - but this GIF would be inside app window identicating progress. Note this app is pure J2SE, without JFace or RCP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This one is also working example code based upon Eclipse article about [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Animation). I was trying to make a *slideshow* or *animated gif* ***dialog*** from images located in a folder. posted here because it could be useful for somenone.

```
public class GifDialog extends Dialog {

    Shell                    dialog;
    private Canvas           canvas;
    int                      numberImage     = 1;
    private volatile boolean running         = true;
    final List<Image>        imageCollection = new ArrayList<Image>();

    DenemeDialog(Shell parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public String open() {
        Shell parent = getParent();
        this.func();
        dialog = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setSize(600, 400);
        dialog.setText("Show Begins!!!");

        Monitor primary = dialog.getDisplay().getPrimaryMonitor();
        Rectangle bounds = primary.getBounds();
        Rectangle rect = dialog.getBounds();

        int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - rect.width) / 2;
        int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - rect.height) / 2;

        dialog.setLocation(x, y);

        dialog.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dialog, SWT.NONE);
        final Image image = new Image(dialog.getDisplay(), imageCollection.get(
                0).getImageData());
        final GC gc = new GC(image);
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
                event.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            }
        });

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (running) {

                    dialog.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            numberImage = numberImage == imageCollection.size() - 1
                                    ? 0 : numberImage + 1;
                            ImageData nextFrameData = imageCollection.get(
                                    numberImage).getImageData();
                            Image frameImage = new Image(dialog.getDisplay(),
                                    nextFrameData);
                            gc.drawImage(frameImage, nextFrameData.x,
                                    nextFrameData.y);
                            frameImage.dispose();
                            canvas.redraw();
                            if (numberImage == 0)
                                try {
                                    running = false;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        };
        dialog.open();
        thread.start();

        Display display = parent.getDisplay();
        while (!dialog.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        return "After Dialog";
    }

    public void func() {

        File path = new File("..\folder");

        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) { // this line weeds out other
                // directories/folders
                try {
                    ImageData imageData = new ImageData(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(loadImage(files[i])));
                    final Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(),
                            imageData);
                    imageCollection.add(image);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public byte[] loadImage(File file) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: None of the examples that rely on SWT's ImageLoader.class will work on GTK Linux SWT, as there is currently a bug that hard-codes the maximum frames to 32 and sets the delay between frames incorrectly.
See [GTK ImageLoader.java](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/975011388a62584b52141fff2fa5c3d16ff4ec33/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/ImageLoader.java)

```
            // Fix the number of GIF frames as GdkPixbufAnimation does not provide an API to
            // determine number of frames.
            int num_frames = 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my solution right here in case anyone stumbles across it:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

import java.nio.file.Path;

final class GIFWidget extends Composite {
    GIFWidget(Composite parent, Path gifFilePath) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        this.gifFilePath = gifFilePath.toAbsolutePath();
    }

    void show() {
        if (!this.isAnimating) {
            this.isAnimating = true;
            this.startAnimationThread();
        }
    }

    void hide() {
        this.isAnimating = false;
    }

    private void startAnimationThread() {
        GC gc = new GC(this);
        Thread animationThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (this.isAnimating && !this.isDisposed()) {
                try {
                    this.getDisplay().asyncExec(() ->
                        this.drawNextImage(gc)
                    );
                    int delayTime = this.getCurrentDelayTime();
                    Thread.sleep(delayTime * DELAY_TIME_MULTIPLIER);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!this.isDisposed()) {
                this.getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
                    this.clearDrawing(gc);
                    gc.dispose();
                });
            }
        });
        animationThread.setDaemon(true);
        animationThread.start();
    }

    private void drawNextImage(GC gc) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = this.getImageLoader();
        if (imageLoader.data != null) {
            ImageData imageData = imageLoader.data[this.imageIndex];
            this.drawImage(gc, imageData);
            this.imageIndex = (this.imageIndex + 1) % imageLoader.data.length;
        }
    }

    private void drawImage(GC gc, ImageData imageData) {
        Image image = new Image(this.getDisplay(), imageData);
        Point size = this.getSize();
        gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageData.width, imageData.height, 0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        image.dispose();
    }

    private void clearDrawing(GC gc) {
        Point size = this.getSize();
        gc.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
    }

    private int getCurrentDelayTime() {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = this.getImageLoader();
        if (imageLoader.data != null) {
            return imageLoader.data[this.imageIndex].delayTime;
        } else {
            return DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME;
        }
    }

    private ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        if (this.imageLoader == null) {
            this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
            this.imageLoader.load(this.gifFilePath.toString());
        }
        return this.imageLoader;
    }

    private final Path gifFilePath;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private boolean isAnimating = false;
    private int imageIndex = 0;

    private static final int DELAY_TIME_MULTIPLIER = 5;
    private static final int DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME = 1;
}
```